# asp.net datagrid custom paging with pages of various sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, paging

I am trying to add paging to my datagrid. This datagrid stores hierarchical data. So the top row has several children rows that need to go beneath it. When a new top row type is going to be added I want to make a new page. This way all related rows will be displayed on the same page. So, I think the tricky part might be making pages with varying sizes. I am not sure how to go about attacking this issue. All of the custom paging examples I have seen still have x amount of rows per page. Like I said my pages have to all be various sizes.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the top row will always be the parent row and you want all its child rows to show up underneath it?  Will there be multiple parent rows per page?

Comment: There will not be multiple parent rows per page. I want one "family" per page. So, some pages might have as few as one row, while others could have 20, just depending on how many child rows belong to that parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use a FormView control for your parents and then bind your children to a grid inside of it.